# Confusion regarding fglrx in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, fglrx, catalyst

I have an ubuntu 12.04 system with an amd radeon hd 4670 graphics card running beautifully. I am interested in upgrading to 12.10 but unsure about catalyst (fglrx) support for the card. the latest driver doesn't support the card. Can i use the legacy (12.6) driver for ubuntu 12.10. Is the support available through jockey? Does the legacy driver support the X-org server in 12.10? is there a ppa or way to downgrade the X-server? Thanks in advance

Comment: No, you cannot use legacy driver. It support only xserver 1.12 while ubuntu 12.10 use 1.13. Therefore there is no ubuntu 12.10 support at the moment. It will not appear in jockey. As for the last question - i didn't try to do that, so i have no idea.

Answer (score 3):

I don't use a 4xxx series card but there is a new PPA available for the purpose you describe.

instructions here: http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/10/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-legacy.html